# Selenium and Postman integration or other approach?

Tags: api, selenium, postman

I am looking for general idea, approach and subsequently a right tool.
I plan to start testing administration panel. Stable parts of it can be tested by mean of selenium-python scripts. But the challange starts when before testing some funcionalities in panel I need to sent a batch of data via Postman to API endpoint.

As you know Postman is a native app, so it doesn't offer a url which selenium driver could access (browser extension is deprecated.

So the question is. Would it be possible to integrate and automate the process in one selenium script?

Is it possible to do it with Postman or there is another tool that can send a request to endpoint and can be integrated with selenium script?

One more thing. The best approach would be: Sending request and few second after that action start selenium test on data which have been delivered via request to panel. I need to fully automate the process and set those actions with no sighnificant time delay.

Curious about possible solutions.

Answer (score 4):

For API Automation purpose, Use Rest Assured. Its easy to learn, implement. You'll be able to fully automate apis(both JSON & XML). All the validation will be done in seconds. If you integrate RestAssured & Selenium, you'll be able to validate data with API & front end.
Please let me know if you need to know more on this.

Sample GET Code :-

```
RestAssured.baseURI="base url Eg :- https://www.google.com/";given().header("Accept","application/json").header("Authorization","Value").when().get("rest of the part of the url").then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).and().body("name[0]",equalTo("Location"));
```

Sample POST Code :-

RestAssured.baseURI="https://www.google.com/";

```
        Response res=given().header("Authorization","Value").header("cache-control","no-cache").header("content-type","application/json").body("{"+"\"format\":[\"live-blog\",\"video-story\",\"Photo Gallery\",\"photo-gallery\",\"blank\",\"breaking-news\",\"photo-story\"],"+"\"language\": \"english\""+"}").when().post("Rest of the url`enter code here`").
```

then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();

```
        String res_string= res.asString();
        System.out.println(res_string);

        JsonPath jpath = new JsonPath(res_string);

        String articleid = jpath.get("[0].articleId");
            System.out.println(articleid);
```

You can find all the jar files online.
Apologies for the format.

Comment: Even if OP doesn't need more information, you can add some code samples and/or some links where to find more information about it. It can be useful for the future readers

Comment: @ann Using rest assured, you'll be able to test all types of APIs(GET,POST,PUT & DELETE). So as you asked , you can use it to feed data into some system pretty quickly. You just need to have a sample request & the url you want to hit. U'll be able to automate it very easily.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov sure. I've added a sample get request. U'll find the jar files online. Do let me know in case of any issue regarding this.                          RestAssured.baseURI="base url Eg :- https://www.google.com/";
given().
   header("Accept","application/json").
   header("Authorization","Value").

  
   
  
  when().
   get("rest of the part of the url ").
  
  then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).and().
  body("name[0]",equalTo("Location"));

Comment: Added it in my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium purpose is not testing your app's APIs, but web.
 I would suggest as someone commented here, use Java with Rest-Assured, it's very reliable, easy to learn, and fast.
You can use Java's API call if you need anything specific for your web testing, as a requirement or something else.

Comment: Actually in my case I don't need to test API, just need deliver data by request, to test all funcionalities of panel. Panel has an url, and can be tested by selenium. So lets imagine one selenium-python script. It starts from request (sending data to panel), data are sent, after few seconds web driver goes to panel url and start testing funcionalities which depends on data sent by request. Is it possible at all or I need separate steps? For example do some time sinchronization? Sent request via Postman at 10:30, start selenium test at 10:31.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Python already, you could easily use the '[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org)' python package to send your API requests and parse the responses as required. This would allow you to easily integrate this into your overall script, sending the api requests, ensuring the necessary response, then starting the selenium steps.

Comment: Test script is in Python, but API is PHP. Would it be  still possible to send request by means of http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ ?

Comment: Sure!  You just have to submit a request in the form that the server expects, which is what you'd be doing with Postman

Comment: Thanks all for feedback. For me integration with python request package worked well. This is exactly what I tried to achieve.